# how to calculate the minimum and maximum of treemap

Tags: highcharts

[image]

I make a `tree map` like this picture , minimum number of value is -2000 and the tree map get the minimum range from -10K .
How can I get -10K? Is there any option to reach to this value in tree map? How can I calculate it? all of values of heatmap are dynamic and change in each second , maybe after one second the range change to -10 to +10

Answer (score 0):

You can define [min](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#colorAxis) param in colorAxis.

```
colorAxis: {
            min: 1
        },
```